# Why am I receiving numpy error in pycharm?

Tags: python, numpy, module, pycharm, conda

When I am doing my project, I got an error when importing numpy package. When I run it gives me error as shown below:

```
  File "C:\Users\mehth\anaconda3\envs\Traffic Sign Model\lib\numpy\__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.__config__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Education/Traffic Sign Model/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\mehth\anaconda3\envs\Traffic Sign Model\lib\numpy\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using python 3.6 and numpy version 1.19.2. I am using Pycharm and conda environment. Please give me the solution. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to import it in numpy's source directory?

Comment: I think so. @kastet6398. I am just a beginner, So I didn't much.

Comment: So, this is the problem. Try to navigate to your project directory and try to import the library again.

Comment: I know the error says that it is being imported in the numpy source directory, but the error message also shows that the import statement is coming from `"D:/Education/Traffic Sign Model/test.py"`, which is on a whole separate drive from the numpy source code (the error shows that numpy is located in their virtual environment on the C drive).

Comment: OP, go to the start menu, open "Anaconda Prompt", activate your environment (`conda activate "Traffic Sign Model"`), and then enter `python`. This should open a Python interactive environment in the terminal. Try entering the command `import numpy as np`. Does that give an error?